# Vue data model change not reflected in bound component

Tags: datepicker, vuejs2, vue-component

A jQuery datepicker is wrappped in a Vue component. The component emits an update message used to update the app model.

The app has two datepicker input fields:

- `startDate`
- `adjustmentDate`

When `startDate` is modified, `adjustmentDate` is to be updated to the next first or fifteenth of the month. However, the `adjustmentDate` datepicker component is not being notified of the update.

Expected behaviour:

- `startDate` datepicker `onSelect` triggers the Vue component `emit` which is captured by Vue method `updateStartDate`
- method `updateStartDate` sets model property `adjustmentDate`

It was hoped this would trigger the `adjustmentDate` component update since the `adjustmentDate` model attribute is bound to the datepicker `componentDate` property which has a watch.

But changing the model doesn't have the affect of notifying the component.

Any suggestions how to do this properly and show the newly calculated `adjustmentDate` when the `startDate` is changed?

**Demo code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

    <div id="app">

        <div><label>Start date</label></div>
        <div>
            <date-picker 
                v-model="startDate"
                v-bind:component-date="startDate"
                date-format="yy-mm-dd"
                @update-date="updateStartDate"
                v-once
            ></date-picker>
        </div>

        <div><label>Adjustment date</label></div>
        <div>
            <date-picker
                v-model="adjustmentDate"
                v-bind:component-date="adjustmentDate"
                date-format="yy-mm-dd"
                @update-date="updateAdjustmentDate"
                v-once
            ></date-picker>
        </div>

    </div>



    <script>

    Vue.component('date-picker', {

        props: ['dateFormat', 'componentDate'],

        template: '<input/>',


        mounted: function() {

        var self = this;

        var _convertDateStringToDate = function(dateString) {
                var dateParts = dateString.split("-");
                var year = dateParts[0];
                var month = dateParts[1];
                var dayOfMonth = dateParts[2];
                return new Date(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        };


        $(this.$el).datepicker({

                dateFormat: this.dateFormat,

                onSelect: function(date) {
                        self.$emit('update-date', _convertDateStringToDate(date));
                },

                onClose: function(date) {
                        self.$emit('update-date', _convertDateStringToDate(date));
                }

        });

        $(this.$el).datepicker('setDate', this.componentDate);

        },


        watch: {
            componentDate: function(newValue, oldValue) {
                $(this.$el).datepicker('setDate', this.componentDate);
            }
        },


        beforeDestroy: function() {
            $(this.$el).datepicker('hide').datepicker('destroy');
        }

    });



    var _calculateAdjustmentDate = function(date) {

        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var dayOfMonth = date.getDate();

        if (dayOfMonth > 15) {
            month = month + 1;
            dayOfMonth = 1;
        } else if (dayOfMonth > 1 && dayOfMonth < 15) {
            dayOfMonth = 15;
        }

        return new Date(year, month, dayOfMonth);

    };


    var data = function() {

        var now = new Date();

        return {
                startDate: now,
                adjustmentDate: _calculateAdjustmentDate(now),
        };

    };


    new Vue({

        el: '#app',

        data: data,

        methods: {

                updateStartDate: function(date) {
                        this.startDate = date;
                        this.adjustmentDate = _calculateAdjustmentDate(date);
                },

                updateAdjustmentDate: function(date) {
                        this.adjustmentDate = date;
                },

        }

    });


    </script>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the [v-once](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) directive from your adjustment date component as it prevents re-rendering when the data changes.

Additionally, you can simply put `_calculateAdjustmentDate` into a computed property, see [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

See your updated example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQYarZ

There are some other issues with your code, I suggest you look into the [Vue guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/), especially at Method Event Handlers and Computed Properties as well as into Reactivity in Depth.

Also, `_calculateAdjustmentDate` does not really do what you describe, so you might look into this as well. You might consider [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thank-you. Could you elaborate on how `_calculateAdjustmentDate` is not behaving as expected?

Comment: `2018-01-01 -> 2018-02-01`, 
`2018-01-02 -> 2018-02-15`, 
`2018-01-16 -> 2018-03-01`
It seems to be one month off.

Comment: `_convertDateStringToDate` was incorrect.  Should be `return new Date(year, month - 1, dayOfMonth);`.  Yes, I'll look at moment.js. Thanks.